# How to add my OVH account to Outlook Microsoft 365 Apps?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

I have been using MS Outlook on Windows as a mail client for my OVH email without any problem for years.
Recently, I had a sync issue which is not related to OVH (my email works on OVH webmail).
I managed to delete my account, thinking that I would simply add my account again.
Having tried many times, I failed.
I deinstalled/reinstalled all Office suite, with no result.
I want to sync in IMAP.
I still get the same troubles (see how I try to add my account in IMAP in screenshots).
Would anyone be able to help me with this? I would be eternally grateful!

Chloe

enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tmtg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1UbC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gguev.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncFPF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to further confirm if the issue is related to Outlook client, it's suggested that you could try to add other account(just like Outlook.com account or Gmail account) to check if you can add them successfully.

And based on my research on OVH account, I found two articles about configuring account, please check if your account is an Email Pro or a MX Plan account and try the different Server and port:

- Email Pro account: [Configuring Email Pro address in Outlook for
  Windows](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/emails-pro/configuration-outlook-2016/)
- MX Plan account: [Configuring MX Plan email addresss in
  Outlook for Windows](https://docs.ovh.com/ie/en/emails/configuration-outlook-2016/)

In addition, it is also suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account to check if there are some differences.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.